# How do I create a long-lived reference into a collection that I know will no longer be modified?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm implementing a bytecode VM and am struggling referencing data stored in a parsed representation of the bytecode. As is the nature of (most) bytecode, it and thus its parsed representation remain unmodified once it's initialized. A separate `Vm` contains the mutable parts (stack etc.) along with that module. I made an MCVE with additional explanatory comments to illustrate the problem; it's at the bottom and on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=63e81f42cbcd720b50bdfd45b85c29e9). The parsed bytecode may look like this:

```
Module { struct_types: {"Bar": StructType::Named(["a", "b"])} }
```

The strings `"Bar"`, `"a"`, `"b"` are references into the bytecode and have lifetime `'b`, so we also have lifetimes in the types `Module<'b>` and `StructType<'b>`.

After creating this, I will want to create struct instances, think `let bar = Bar { a: (), b: () };`. At least currently, each struct instance needs to hold a reference to its type, so that type might look like this:

```rust
pub struct Struct<'b> {
    struct_type: &'b bytecode::StructType<'b>,
    fields: Vec<Value<'b>>,
}
```

The values of a struct's fields may be constants whose value is stored in the bytecode, so the `Value` enum has a lifetime `'b` as well, and that works. The problem is that I have a `&'b bytecode::StructType<'b>` in the first field: **how do I get a reference that lives long enough?** I think the reference *would* actually be valid long enough.

The part of the code that I suspect to be the critical one is here:

```rust
        pub fn struct_type(&self, _name: &str) -> Option<&'b StructType<'b>> {
            // self.struct_types.get(name)
            todo!("fix lifetime problems")
        }
```

With the commented out code, I can't get a `'b` reference because the reference `self.struct_types` lives too short; to fix that I'd need to do `&'b self` which would spread virally through the code; also, most of the times I need to borrow the `Vm` mutably, which doesn't work if all those exclusive self references have to live long.

Introducing a separate lifetime `'m` so that I could return a `&'m StructType<'b>` sounds like something that I could try as well, but that sounds just as viral and in addition introduces a separate lifetime I need to keep track of; being able to replace `'b` with `'m` (or at least only having on in each place) would be a bit nicer.

Finally this feels like something that pinning could be helpful with, but I don't understand that topic enough to make an educated guess on how that could be approached.

---

MCVE

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

mod bytecode {
    use std::collections::BTreeMap;
    
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
    pub enum StructType<'b> {
        /// unit struct type; doesn't have fields
        Empty,
        /// tuple struct type; fields are positional
        Positional(usize),
        /// "normal" struct type; fields are named
        Named(Vec<&'b str>),
    }
        
    impl<'b> StructType<'b> {
        pub fn field_count(&self) -> usize {
            match self {
                Self::Empty => 0,
                Self::Positional(field_count) => *field_count,
                Self::Named(fields) => fields.len(),
            }
        }
    }
    
    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Module<'b> {
        struct_types: BTreeMap<&'b str, StructType<'b>>,
    }

    impl<'b> Module<'b> {
        // here is the problem: I would like to return a reference with lifetime 'b.
        // from the point I start executing instructions, I know that I won't modify
        // the module (particularly, I won't add entries to the map), so I think that
        // lifetime should be possible - pinning? `&'b self` everywhere? idk
        pub fn struct_type(&self, _name: &str) -> Option<&'b StructType<'b>> {
            // self.struct_types.get(name)
            todo!("fix lifetime problems")
        }
    }
    
    pub fn parse<'b>(bytecode: &'b str) -> Module<'b> {
        // this would use nom to parse actual bytecode
        assert_eq!(bytecode, "struct Bar { a, b }");

        let bar = &bytecode[7..10];
        let a = &bytecode[13..14];
        let b = &bytecode[16..17];

        let fields = vec![a, b];
        let bar_struct = StructType::Named(fields);
        let struct_types = BTreeMap::from_iter([
            (bar, bar_struct),
        ]);
        Module { struct_types }
    }
}

mod vm {
    use crate::bytecode::{self, StructType};

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub enum Value<'b> {
        Unit,
        Struct(Struct<'b>),
    }
    
    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Struct<'b> {
        struct_type: &'b bytecode::StructType<'b>,
        fields: Vec<Value<'b>>,
    }

    impl<'b> Struct<'b> {
        pub fn new(struct_type: &'b bytecode::StructType<'b>, fields: Vec<Value<'b>>) -> Self {
            Struct { struct_type, fields }
        }
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Vm<'b> {
        module: bytecode::Module<'b>,
    }

    impl<'b> Vm<'b> {
        pub fn new(module: bytecode::Module<'b>) -> Self {
            Self { module }
        }

        pub fn create_struct(&mut self, type_name: &'b str) -> Value<'b> {
            let struct_type: &'b StructType<'b> = self.module.struct_type(type_name).unwrap();
            // just initialize the fields to something, we don't care
            let fields = vec![Value::Unit; struct_type.field_count()];

            let value = Value::Struct(Struct::new(struct_type, fields));
            value
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    // the bytecode contains all constants needed at runtime;
    // we're just interested in how struct types are handled
    // obviously the real bytecode is not as human-readable
    let bytecode = "struct Bar { a, b }";
    // we parse that into a module that, among other things,
    // has a map of all struct types
    let module = bytecode::parse(bytecode);
    println!("{:?}", module);

    // we create a Vm that is capable of running commands
    // that are stored in the module
    let mut vm = vm::Vm::new(module);

    // now we try to execute an instruction to create a struct value
    // the instruction for this contains a reference to the type name
    // stored in the bytecode.
    // the struct value contains a reference to its type and holds its field values.
    let value = {
        let bar = &bytecode[7..10];
        vm.create_struct(bar)
    };
    println!("{:?}", value);
}
```

Comment: @ChayimFriedman this is not a self referential struct problem, but one declaring the wrong lifetimes, see [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7b0cdc132213b51a4124a83f4c1fb98e)

Comment: @cafce25 I assume the OP cannot change `create_struct()`'s signature and it must have it returning `Value<'b>`.

Comment: it may be possible to introduce that timeline (I called it `'m` for Module). I hoped to find that there's a way that requires less viral means.

I don't think this question is a duplicate of the linked question. my Module depends on bytecode, and my Vm (and values managed by it) depends on Module, so there's no self references. I may *want* to go that way if pinning is a tool that can do it, but the linked question itself does not go into details of pinning, just points to a different question (that I will look at).

Comment: `&'b bytecode::StructType<'b>` feels wrong, if `StructType` already carries the lifetime, then why have a reference to it with the same lifetime? I suspect those have to be different lifetimes, like `&'c bytecode::StructType<'b>`.

Comment: Yes, pretty sure that that's your problem. You can't use the same lifetime to reference `&str` parts of the bytecode **and** to descripe references to `StructType` objects. Those have to be different lifetimes, I'm quite certain it will just magically work then. I don't see anything majorly wrong with your code then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&'b bytecode::StructType<'b>` is a classic anti-pattern in Rust, it strongly indicates incorrectly annotated lifetimes. It doesn't make sense that an object would depend on some lifetime and borrowing it creates the same lifetime. That is very rare to happen on purpose.

So I suspect you need two lifetimes, which I will call `'m` and `'b`:

- `'b`: the lifetime of the `bytecode` string, everything that references it will use `&'b str`.
- `'m`: the lifetime of the `Module` object. Everything that references it or its contained `StructType` will use this lifetime.

If split into two lifetimes and adjusted correctly, it simply works:

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

mod bytecode {
    use std::{collections::BTreeMap, iter::FromIterator};

    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
    pub enum StructType<'b> {
        /// unit struct type; doesn't have fields
        Empty,
        /// tuple struct type; fields are positional
        Positional(usize),
        /// "normal" struct type; fields are named
        Named(Vec<&'b str>),
    }

    impl<'b> StructType<'b> {
        pub fn field_count(&self) -> usize {
            match self {
                Self::Empty => 0,
                Self::Positional(field_count) => *field_count,
                Self::Named(fields) => fields.len(),
            }
        }
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Module<'b> {
        struct_types: BTreeMap<&'b str, StructType<'b>>,
    }

    impl<'b> Module<'b> {
        // here is the problem: I would like to return a reference with lifetime 'b.
        // from the point I start executing instructions, I know that I won't modify
        // the module (particularly, I won't add entries to the map), so I think that
        // lifetime should be possible - pinning? `&'b self` everywhere? idk
        pub fn struct_type(&self, name: &str) -> Option<&StructType<'b>> {
            self.struct_types.get(name)
        }
    }

    pub fn parse<'b>(bytecode: &'b str) -> Module<'b> {
        // this would use nom to parse actual bytecode
        assert_eq!(bytecode, "struct Bar { a, b }");

        let bar = &bytecode[7..10];
        let a = &bytecode[13..14];
        let b = &bytecode[16..17];

        let fields = vec![a, b];
        let bar_struct = StructType::Named(fields);
        let struct_types = BTreeMap::from_iter([(bar, bar_struct)]);
        Module { struct_types }
    }
}

mod vm {
    use crate::bytecode::{self, StructType};

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub enum Value<'b, 'm> {
        Unit,
        Struct(Struct<'b, 'm>),
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Struct<'b, 'm> {
        struct_type: &'m bytecode::StructType<'b>,
        fields: Vec<Value<'b, 'm>>,
    }

    impl<'b, 'm> Struct<'b, 'm> {
        pub fn new(struct_type: &'m bytecode::StructType<'b>, fields: Vec<Value<'b, 'm>>) -> Self {
            Struct {
                struct_type,
                fields,
            }
        }
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Vm<'b> {
        module: bytecode::Module<'b>,
    }

    impl<'b> Vm<'b> {
        pub fn new(module: bytecode::Module<'b>) -> Self {
            Self { module }
        }

        pub fn create_struct(&mut self, type_name: &str) -> Value<'b, '_> {
            let struct_type: &StructType<'b> = self.module.struct_type(type_name).unwrap();
            // just initialize the fields to something, we don't care
            let fields = vec![Value::Unit; struct_type.field_count()];

            let value = Value::Struct(Struct::new(struct_type, fields));
            value
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    // the bytecode contains all constants needed at runtime;
    // we're just interested in how struct types are handled
    // obviously the real bytecode is not as human-readable
    let bytecode = "struct Bar { a, b }";
    // we parse that into a module that, among other things,
    // has a map of all struct types
    let module = bytecode::parse(bytecode);
    println!("{:?}", module);

    // we create a Vm that is capable of running commands
    // that are stored in the module
    let mut vm = vm::Vm::new(module);

    // now we try to execute an instruction to create a struct value
    // the instruction for this contains a reference to the type name
    // stored in the bytecode.
    // the struct value contains a reference to its type and holds its field values.
    let value = {
        let bar = &bytecode[7..10];
        vm.create_struct(bar)
    };
    println!("{:?}", value);
}
```

```
Module { struct_types: {"Bar": Named(["a", "b"])} }
Struct(Struct { struct_type: Named(["a", "b"]), fields: [Unit, Unit] })
```

---

It can further be simplified, however, due to the fact that `'m` is connected to `'b`, and therefore everything that depends on `'m` automatically also has access to `'b` objects, because `'b` is guaranteed to outlive `'m`.

Therefore, let's introduce `'a`, which we will now use inside of the `vm` mod to reference anything from the `bytecode` mod. This will further allow lifetime elysion to happen at a couple of points, simplifying the code even further:

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

mod bytecode {
    use std::{collections::BTreeMap, iter::FromIterator};

    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
    pub enum StructType<'b> {
        /// unit struct type; doesn't have fields
        Empty,
        /// tuple struct type; fields are positional
        Positional(usize),
        /// "normal" struct type; fields are named
        Named(Vec<&'b str>),
    }

    impl<'b> StructType<'b> {
        pub fn field_count(&self) -> usize {
            match self {
                Self::Empty => 0,
                Self::Positional(field_count) => *field_count,
                Self::Named(fields) => fields.len(),
            }
        }
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Module<'b> {
        struct_types: BTreeMap<&'b str, StructType<'b>>,
    }

    impl<'b> Module<'b> {
        // here is the problem: I would like to return a reference with lifetime 'b.
        // from the point I start executing instructions, I know that I won't modify
        // the module (particularly, I won't add entries to the map), so I think that
        // lifetime should be possible - pinning? `&'b self` everywhere? idk
        pub fn struct_type(&self, name: &str) -> Option<&StructType<'b>> {
            self.struct_types.get(name)
        }
    }

    pub fn parse<'b>(bytecode: &'b str) -> Module<'b> {
        // this would use nom to parse actual bytecode
        assert_eq!(bytecode, "struct Bar { a, b }");

        let bar = &bytecode[7..10];
        let a = &bytecode[13..14];
        let b = &bytecode[16..17];

        let fields = vec![a, b];
        let bar_struct = StructType::Named(fields);
        let struct_types = BTreeMap::from_iter([(bar, bar_struct)]);
        Module { struct_types }
    }
}

mod vm {
    use crate::bytecode::{self, StructType};

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub enum Value<'a> {
        Unit,
        Struct(Struct<'a>),
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Struct<'a> {
        struct_type: &'a bytecode::StructType<'a>,
        fields: Vec<Value<'a>>,
    }

    impl<'a> Struct<'a> {
        pub fn new(struct_type: &'a bytecode::StructType, fields: Vec<Value<'a>>) -> Self {
            Struct {
                struct_type,
                fields,
            }
        }
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Vm<'a> {
        module: bytecode::Module<'a>,
    }

    impl<'a> Vm<'a> {
        pub fn new(module: bytecode::Module<'a>) -> Self {
            Self { module }
        }

        pub fn create_struct(&mut self, type_name: &str) -> Value {
            let struct_type: &StructType = self.module.struct_type(type_name).unwrap();
            // just initialize the fields to something, we don't care
            let fields = vec![Value::Unit; struct_type.field_count()];

            let value = Value::Struct(Struct::new(struct_type, fields));
            value
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    // the bytecode contains all constants needed at runtime;
    // we're just interested in how struct types are handled
    // obviously the real bytecode is not as human-readable
    let bytecode = "struct Bar { a, b }";
    // we parse that into a module that, among other things,
    // has a map of all struct types
    let module = bytecode::parse(bytecode);
    println!("{:?}", module);

    // we create a Vm that is capable of running commands
    // that are stored in the module
    let mut vm = vm::Vm::new(module);

    // now we try to execute an instruction to create a struct value
    // the instruction for this contains a reference to the type name
    // stored in the bytecode.
    // the struct value contains a reference to its type and holds its field values.
    let value = {
        let bar = &bytecode[7..10];
        vm.create_struct(bar)
    };
    println!("{:?}", value);
}
```

```
Module { struct_types: {"Bar": Named(["a", "b"])} }
Struct(Struct { struct_type: Named(["a", "b"]), fields: [Unit, Unit] })
```

**Fun fact:** This is now one of the rare cases where we legitimately have to use `&'a bytecode::StructType<'a>`, so take my opening statement with a grain of salt, and you were kind of right all along :)

---

The crazy thing is if we then rename `'a` to `'b` to be consistent with your original code, we get almost your code with only some minor differences:

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

mod bytecode {
    use std::{collections::BTreeMap, iter::FromIterator};

    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
    pub enum StructType<'b> {
        /// unit struct type; doesn't have fields
        Empty,
        /// tuple struct type; fields are positional
        Positional(usize),
        /// "normal" struct type; fields are named
        Named(Vec<&'b str>),
    }

    impl<'b> StructType<'b> {
        pub fn field_count(&self) -> usize {
            match self {
                Self::Empty => 0,
                Self::Positional(field_count) => *field_count,
                Self::Named(fields) => fields.len(),
            }
        }
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Module<'b> {
        struct_types: BTreeMap<&'b str, StructType<'b>>,
    }

    impl<'b> Module<'b> {
        // here is the problem: I would like to return a reference with lifetime 'b.
        // from the point I start executing instructions, I know that I won't modify
        // the module (particularly, I won't add entries to the map), so I think that
        // lifetime should be possible - pinning? `&'b self` everywhere? idk
        pub fn struct_type(&self, name: &str) -> Option<&StructType<'b>> {
            self.struct_types.get(name)
        }
    }

    pub fn parse<'b>(bytecode: &'b str) -> Module<'b> {
        // this would use nom to parse actual bytecode
        assert_eq!(bytecode, "struct Bar { a, b }");

        let bar = &bytecode[7..10];
        let a = &bytecode[13..14];
        let b = &bytecode[16..17];

        let fields = vec![a, b];
        let bar_struct = StructType::Named(fields);
        let struct_types = BTreeMap::from_iter([(bar, bar_struct)]);
        Module { struct_types }
    }
}

mod vm {
    use crate::bytecode::{self, StructType};

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub enum Value<'b> {
        Unit,
        Struct(Struct<'b>),
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Struct<'b> {
        struct_type: &'b bytecode::StructType<'b>,
        fields: Vec<Value<'b>>,
    }

    impl<'b> Struct<'b> {
        pub fn new(struct_type: &'b bytecode::StructType, fields: Vec<Value<'b>>) -> Self {
            Struct {
                struct_type,
                fields,
            }
        }
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
    pub struct Vm<'b> {
        module: bytecode::Module<'b>,
    }

    impl<'b> Vm<'b> {
        pub fn new(module: bytecode::Module<'b>) -> Self {
            Self { module }
        }

        pub fn create_struct(&mut self, type_name: &str) -> Value {
            let struct_type: &StructType = self.module.struct_type(type_name).unwrap();
            // just initialize the fields to something, we don't care
            let fields = vec![Value::Unit; struct_type.field_count()];

            let value = Value::Struct(Struct::new(struct_type, fields));
            value
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    // the bytecode contains all constants needed at runtime;
    // we're just interested in how struct types are handled
    // obviously the real bytecode is not as human-readable
    let bytecode = "struct Bar { a, b }";
    // we parse that into a module that, among other things,
    // has a map of all struct types
    let module = bytecode::parse(bytecode);
    println!("{:?}", module);

    // we create a Vm that is capable of running commands
    // that are stored in the module
    let mut vm = vm::Vm::new(module);

    // now we try to execute an instruction to create a struct value
    // the instruction for this contains a reference to the type name
    // stored in the bytecode.
    // the struct value contains a reference to its type and holds its field values.
    let value = {
        let bar = &bytecode[7..10];
        vm.create_struct(bar)
    };
    println!("{:?}", value);
}
```

```
Module { struct_types: {"Bar": Named(["a", "b"])} }
Struct(Struct { struct_type: Named(["a", "b"]), fields: [Unit, Unit] })
```

So the actual fix for your original code is as follows:

```
4c4
<     use std::collections::BTreeMap;
---
>     use std::{collections::BTreeMap, iter::FromIterator};
36,38c36,37
<         pub fn struct_type(&self, _name: &str) -> Option<&'b StructType<'b>> {
<             // self.struct_types.get(name)
<             todo!("fix lifetime problems")
---
>         pub fn struct_type(&self, name: &str) -> Option<&StructType<'b>> {
>             self.struct_types.get(name)
73c72
<         pub fn new(struct_type: &'b bytecode::StructType<'b>, fields: Vec<Value<'b>>) -> Self {
---
>         pub fn new(struct_type: &'b bytecode::StructType, fields: Vec<Value<'b>>) -> Self {
91,92c90,91
<         pub fn create_struct(&mut self, type_name: &'b str) -> Value<'b> {
<             let struct_type: &'b StructType<'b> = self.module.struct_type(type_name).unwrap();
---
>         pub fn create_struct(&mut self, type_name: &str) -> Value {
>             let struct_type: &StructType = self.module.struct_type(type_name).unwrap();
```

I hope deriving them step by step made it somewhat clear why those changes are necessary.